# Collaborative coding platform in the style of Google Colab

Tags: hpc

(I hope this question is fitting for this SE, I couldn't find very relevant tags)

I am looking for an online platform in the style of Google [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) with the following requirements:

- possibility to run notebooks like in [JupyterLab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)
- necessity of at least python and julia

and following wishes:

- privacy-focused (even if I am not coding for sensitive projects I don't like the idea that my code is hosted at Google)
- possibility to have a team of 5 (at least) students and coworkers (preferably 10) and the ability to share and version the code
- possibility to pay for more computational power

I am considering free and paid options.

Comment: We used to host our own JupyterLab instance at my previous job. Basically we had it running in a Docker container which had a shared volume mounted. So if rolling your own solution is an option, just go with that approach.

Comment: No, unfortunately it is not possible here.

Comment: What do you mean? You cannot self-host or JupyterLab is not enough?

Comment: Here is some information: https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Thank you for the link. I mean we cannot self-host.